# Access python dictionary with case insensitive string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am struggling to see if there exist a way in order to access a python dictionary with strings as keys with the correct string but case insensitive

For example with this code:

```
dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three', 3}
list = ['One', 'second', 'THree']

for item in list:
    if item in dictionary:
        print(item)
```

I am not able to find a way such that the output is:
`One THree', ie. to compare the keys of the dictionary and the string that I have case insenstively

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not unless you inherit from ``defaultdict`` and modify the getter. But think about this: if you have the keys ``one`` and ``ONE``, then what value would you like to get with ``One``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle case-insenstivity on your end by either converting your `dictionary.keys()` to lower case or `list` elements to lower case or both as:

```
for item in list:
    if item.lower() in map(str.lower, dictionary.keys()):
        print(item)
```

You can either use `lower()` or `upper()`, but you have to be consistent in both the cases.

Answer (score 3):

Create a list of lowercase dictionary keys, then compare the lowercase variants of each item in your list with this list.

```
dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
list = ['One', 'second', 'THree']

for item in list:
    if item.lower() in [key.lower() for key in dictionary.keys()]:
        print(item)
```

Thus:

```
One
THree
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `casefold()` for case insensitive search:

```
dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
list = ['One', 'second', 'THree']

for item in list:
    if item.casefold() in dictionary:
        print(item)
```

A list-comprehension way:

```
print( '\n'.join([item for item in list if item.casefold() in dictionary]))
```

Comment: Casefold does not work if the dictionary keys are Capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

use string method `lower`:

```
dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
list = ['One', 'second', 'THree']

for item in list:
    if item.lower() in dictionary:
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
One
THree
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
list = ['One', 'second', 'THree']

for item in list:
    if item.lower() in [d.lower() for d in dictionary.keys()]:
        print(item)
```

Comment: @Andrea Foderaro Please accept the answer. It does work for you.

Comment: @Marichyasana He wants case insensitive. (as mentioned in the question)

Comment: What means "case insensitive?" The keys can contain upper case in which the match fails.

Comment: Sorry @Leo this isn't case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Try using the python
[`lambda`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/lambdas.html)
keyword:

```
l = ['One', 'second', 'THree']
lc = lambda x: [i for i in x if i.lower() in dictionary]
print(lc(l))
```

Output:

```
['One', 'THree']
```

*Note: i changed the variable name `list` to `l` because list is a python keyword so if you want to call the list keyword it won't call the list keyword instead it will call the list*

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing it is to use [casefold](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) function. This function available from Python 3.3.

Return a casefolded copy of the string. Casefolded strings may be used for caseless matching.

> Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it
>   is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string. For example,
>   the German lowercase letter 'ß' is equivalent to "ss". Since it is
>   already lowercase, lower() would do nothing to 'ß'; casefold()
>   converts it to "ss".
>
> The casefolding algorithm is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode
>   Standard.

```
dictionary = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
list = ["One", "second", "THree"]

print(*(item for item in list if item.casefold() in dictionary), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
One
THree
```